# for-loop appears to be skipping over the main body of my initial block

Tags: system-verilog

I am attempting to run a testbench, with relevant sections outlined below.

```
`timescale 1 ns / 10 ps
module ASS1_T3_tb();

parameter NumBits = 8;

int fd;
logic signed [NumBits:0] jj,kk;

logic signed [2*NumBits-1:0] Output;

ASS1_T3 U1(.M(jj[NumBits-1:0]), .Q(kk[NumBits-1:0]), .O(Output));

initial
begin
    
    $display($time, " << Starting the Simulation >>");
        
    for(jj=0; jj<=(8'sb11111111); jj=jj+1)
        begin 
            $stop;
            for(kk=0; kk<=(8'sb11111111); kk=kk+1)
                begin 
                    #10;                    
                    // Internal logic that I don't think affects the issue
                    // this logic does NOT change jj or kk
                end
        end
        
    $finish();
end

endmodule
```

However, the `for` loop involving "jj" is never actually ran through. I've done similar implementations for other testbenches that did run correctly. The simulation starts and *does not stop* at the "$stop" statement, but skips to the "$finish()" statement.

I am using SystemVerilog, tried both SystemVerilog and good old Verilog formats for the output netlist to Questa, to no avail. I've made very few testbenches before, so any and all help is appreciated. This is the combinational version of the project, I also have tried a sequential testbench, which also skips the `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`8'sb11111111` is a *signed* numeric literal which is the same as decimal -1.  Add this line of code:

```
initial $display("8'sb11111111 is %0d", 8'sb11111111);
```

Output:

```
8'sb11111111 is -1
```

This means the body of the `for` loop with `jj` does not get executed because the following expression is false:

```
jj<=(8'sb11111111)
```

You need to choose another ending condition for the loop.  For example, this would allow the loop to be executed 3 times:

```
for (jj=0; jj<=2; jj=jj+1)
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 5.7.1 *Integer literal constants*